# Apply a SUM function on the product of two fields in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT sum("field1" * "field2") FROM "my_db"."autogen"."data" GROUP BY time(1d) FILL(null)
```

In short I would like to perform the operation `sum` on the product of two fields `field` and `field2`.

The above query returns an error: `expected field argument in sum()`.

Is this kind of thing at all possible in InfluxDB?

Comment: Have you tried `sum("field1") * sum("field2") as SUM` ?

Comment: I can do that, but it’s mathematically different and gives different results.

Comment: make sure `field1` and `field2` are numeric types!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a idea: try Sub Query

Note:I don't have editor right now so it might give error too

```
SELECT SUM(Multiplication) FROM 
    (SELECT  "field1" * "field2" as Multiplication, time(1d) as Days FROM 
        "my_db"."autogen"."data" GROUP BY time(1d) FILL(null)
    ) GROUP BY Days
```